invoke-rc.d: initscript ubuntu-fan, action "start" failed
When I uninstalled and reinstalled docker, the rest of the packages were uninstalled successfully. But when uninstalling to "docker.io", I encountered an error, I tried but could not solve it, I hope someone can help me solve the problem, thank you very much.
The specific error is as follows:1
(base) lenovo@lenovo-07:~/Documents/xieziyang$ dpkg -l | grep docker
rc  docker.io                                  24.0.7-0ubuntu2~20.04.1                                         amd64        Linux container runtime
(base) lenovo@lenovo-07:~/Documents/xieziyang$ sudo apt-get autoremove docker.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'docker.io' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ubuntu-fan (0.12.13ubuntu0.1) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
invoke-rc.d: initscript ubuntu-fan, action "start" failed.
● ubuntu-fan.service - Ubuntu FAN network setup
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ubuntu-fan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-09-12 19:11:13 CST; 1h 8min ago
   Main PID: 2715341 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 629145)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/ubuntu-fan.service

9月 12 19:11:13 lenovo-07 systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu FAN network setup...
9月 12 19:11:13 lenovo-07 systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu FAN network setup.
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-fan (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-fan package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-fan
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


This led to my inability to successfully uninstall 'docker.io'. I have never modified the file '/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d'.
I tried many solutions online, such as executing sudo apt-get install -f to fix the issue, but I still encountered the same error:
(base) lenovo@lenovo-07:~/Documents/xieziyang$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ubuntu-fan (0.12.13ubuntu0.1) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
invoke-rc.d: initscript ubuntu-fan, action "start" failed.
● ubuntu-fan.service - Ubuntu FAN network setup
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ubuntu-fan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-09-12 19:11:13 CST; 1h 9min ago
   Main PID: 2715341 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 629145)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/ubuntu-fan.service

9月 12 19:11:13 lenovo-07 systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu FAN network setup...
9月 12 19:11:13 lenovo-07 systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu FAN network setup.
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-fan (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-fan package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-fan
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

After this, when I executed related commands such as 'apt-get install' or 'apt', this error often occurred, preventing me from successfully installing some software.
(base) lenovo@lenovo-07:~/Documents/xieziyang$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-tools-5.4.0-193 linux-tools-5.4.0-193-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin slirp4netns
Suggested packages:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin slirp4netns
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 122 MB of archives.
After this operation, 440 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/docker-ce/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 containerd.io amd64 1.7.22-1 [29.5 MB]
Get:2 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/docker-ce/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-buildx-plugin amd64 0.16.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [29.9 MB]
Get:3 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/docker-ce/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-cli amd64 5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [15.0 MB]
Get:4 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/docker-ce/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [25.6 MB]
Get:5 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/docker-ce/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-rootless-extras amd64 5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [9,577 kB]                          
Get:6 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/docker-ce/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-compose-plugin amd64 2.29.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [12.5 MB]                                 
Get:7 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 slirp4netns amd64 0.4.3-1 [74.3 kB]                                                                             
Fetched 122 MB in 9s (13.5 MB/s)                                                                                                                                            
Selecting previously unselected package containerd.io.
(Reading database ... 248852 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-containerd.io_1.7.22-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking containerd.io (1.7.22-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-buildx-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../1-docker-buildx-plugin_0.16.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-buildx-plugin (0.16.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../2-docker-ce-cli_5%3a27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-cli (5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
Preparing to unpack .../3-docker-ce_5%3a27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce-rootless-extras.
Preparing to unpack .../4-docker-ce-rootless-extras_5%3a27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-compose-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../5-docker-compose-plugin_2.29.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-compose-plugin (2.29.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package slirp4netns.
Preparing to unpack .../6-slirp4netns_0.4.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slirp4netns (0.4.3-1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-fan (0.12.13ubuntu0.1) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
invoke-rc.d: initscript ubuntu-fan, action "start" failed.
● ubuntu-fan.service - Ubuntu FAN network setup
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ubuntu-fan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-09-12 19:11:13 CST; 1h 39min ago
   Main PID: 2715341 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 629145)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/ubuntu-fan.service

9月 12 19:11:13 lenovo-07 systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu FAN network setup...
9月 12 19:11:13 lenovo-07 systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu FAN network setup.
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-fan (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-fan package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up slirp4netns (0.4.3-1) ...
Setting up docker-buildx-plugin (0.16.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Setting up containerd.io (1.7.22-1) ...
Setting up docker-compose-plugin (2.29.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Setting up docker-ce-cli (5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Setting up docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:27.2.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...

Configuration file '/etc/init.d/docker'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** docker (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? Y
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/docker ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 308: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 317: test: x: unexpected operator
docker.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-fan
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
(base) lenovo@lenovo-07:~/Documents/xieziyang$ systemctl start docker
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'docker.service'.
Authenticating as: lenovo,,, (lenovo)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
(base) lenovo@lenovo-07:~/Documents/xieziyang$ 

I hope someone can help me resolve this issue. Thank you very much

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Details matter.

I solved the problem by forcibly deleting the Ubuntu-fan file, and then reinstalling Ubuntu-fan, no longer reporting errors
